# Room data is lost after my app is restarted

Tags: android, android-room

I have a simple implementation of Room in my app. It has two entities.
It works fine while app is running. But I see no data once app is restarted.

This is my database creation code -

```
@Database(entities = {Person.class, College.class}, version = 1,  exportSchema = true)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppdDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract PersonDao personDao();
    public abstract CollegeDao collgeDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my-sample-app.db")
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) INSTANCE.close();
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

In any running session, I can add and view data but nothing is available after app restart. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: `public static void destroyInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE != null) INSTANCE.close();
    INSTANCE = null;
}` this lines are useless.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake-

I wasn't using ***getInstance()*** posted in question, I was using below code to create database instead -

```
mDb = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(mContext, AppDatabase.class)
```

My code works as intended with original code posted in question.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you had an empty db every time you restart the app is because in your database class you used "Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder.." which is used only for testing purposes on db ,so insteand you should used "Room.databaseBuilder.."

Comment: Yes, that was the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check my code but may be it will work for you. Try this:

```
@Database(entities = {Person.class, College.class}, version = 1)

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppdDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract PersonDao personDao();
    public abstract CollegeDao collgeDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my_sample_app")
                               .build();
            }
        }        
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) INSTANCE.close();
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gautam not much. I only changed the DB name and make synchronized block for the given code. Actually this error occurred when your DB gets corrupted. The DB works fine in any running session but whenever user restart the app, the android system drop the existing corrupted DB and make a new one for the app.

Comment: the only advantage of making synchronized block is in multi-threaded environment. I don't see how it will solve the issue for op & can you tell me what is meant by db is corrupt ? In which scenario it can occur ?

Comment: DB corrupt means when android system not be able to read the DB. Database disk image is malformed. The scenario in which it occur are 1. When the app is killed while writing operation is going on. 2. When you copy the DB from device to PC, insert the data into DB from PC and again copy the DB from PC to device. In this scenario sometimes the DB get corrupt. I have faced both scenario

Answer (score 0):

you used below code and i think your issue will be solved ..
make data base like below code ..

```
@Database(entities = {MyTable.class}, version = 1)
```

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract MyTableDao getTableDao();
}

then after make dao interface..

```
@Dao
```

public interface MyTableDao {
    @Insert
    void insertData(MyTable myTable);

}

and make your pojo class

```
@Entity
```

public class MyTable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private double ItemPrice;

public double getItemPrice() {
    return ItemPrice;
}

public void setItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
    ItemPrice = itemPrice;
}
```

}

than after make one app activity class and called at the application level.

```
public class AppActivity extends Application {
```

static AppDatabase db;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
}

public static AppDatabase getDatabase() {
    return db;
}
```

}

above activity class declared in manifest file in application tag.

```
        android:name=".AppActivity"
```

then after used to insert in main activity like this ..

```
        AppActivity.getDatabase().getTableDao().insertData(yourobject);
```