# My data in Database are deleted everytime I am killing the app?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room, local-database

In my android app, I am storing data in database using Room Database library.I can store and get data in a single session.There is no problem in that. The problem is when I close the app and open again I am not getting the data stored in the local database.Those data are deleted.

I've searched in google and some of them said create room data database instance using databaseBuilder.But I am using that only.but I am getting this error.

This is my instance initialization.

This is my AppDtabase class ;

```
@Database(entities = {SelectedBuilding.class}, exportSchema =true,  version=2)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract SelectedBuildingDao myDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context){
        if (INSTANCE==null){
            INSTANCE= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class,"Selected_buildings")
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance(){
        INSTANCE=null;
    }

    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE selected_building ADD COLUMN Building_Id TEXT");
        }
    };



}

 INSTANCE= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class,"Selected_area").build();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The data actually added in database or not? check it firstly

Comment: I am storing data by calling myDao.insert()...and I am getting data by calling myDao.getData() .Which means data stores in the database right? Or is there any other way to check?

Comment: Can you please post some more code for a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room data is lost after my app is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317198/room-data-is-lost-after-my-app-is-restarted)

Comment: @Sathyan Please share whole code snipped with us to batter understanding

Comment: @SurajBahadur I checked this one. But this is not a solution for me.Because I am not using inMemoryBuilder() for creating instance.

Comment: @ND1010_ I have added my database class here.Kindly check that.